# React Native Dynamically Change View’s Background Color

Tags: javascript, react-native

I’m trying to make an app where the background color changes every time you tap the screen. I have the tap event working, but the I don’t know how to change the background color.

Here is my code right now:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

let randomHex = () => {
    let letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    let color = '#';
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

export default class randomBackground extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)
    }
    onClick() {
        console.log('clicked ')
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={ this.onClick } style={styles.container}>
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.instructions}>
                        Tap to change the background
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: randomHex()
    },
    instructions: {
        color: "white"
    }
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('randomBackground', () => randomBackground);
```

I’d like to have the background regenerate every time the screen is tapped.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can change the background color by using `this.setState`

Set the initial background color in your `constructor`

```js
this.state = {
    backgroundColor: randomHex()
}
```

in your `render` function change your style prop to:

```js
[styles.container, {backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor}]
```

and `onClick` add

```js
this.setState({backgroundColor: randomHex()});
```

Heres the full code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TouchableHighlight,
} from "react-native";

let randomHex = () => {
    let letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    let color = "#";
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
};

export default class randomBackground extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            backgroundColor: randomHex(),
        };
    }

    onClick() {
        console.log("clicked ");
        this.setState({ backgroundColor: randomHex() });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={this.onClick}
                style={[
                    styles.container,
                    { backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor },
                ]}
            >
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.instructions}>Tap to change the background</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: randomHex(),
    },
    instructions: {
        color: "white",
    },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent("randomBackground", () => randomBackground);
```

Comment: Might want to try TouchableWithoutFeedback or TouchableOpacity instead of TouchableHighlight. First, doesn't show any opacity change. Second, shows feedback but performs better.

Comment: For some reason this results in an infinite loop in my case. Only difference is that I'm using the TouchableHighlight within a Native Base ListItem

Answer (score 4):

```
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';



export default class randomBackground extends Component {

    state={
      currentColor:"#FFFFF"
    }

    onClick() {
      let letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
      let color = '#';
      for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
         color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
      }
      this.setState({currentColor:color})
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={ this.onClick.bind(this) } {[styles.container, {backgroundColor: this.state.currentColor}]}>
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.instructions}>
                        Tap to change the background
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    instructions: {
        color: "white"
    }
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('randomBackground', () => randomBackground);
```

Comment: This doesn’t do anything…

Comment: @Hum4n01d you have already tried this code.i have just edited.

Comment: @Yaseminçidem any suggestions on following question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57998696/how-to-detect-styles-hyperlinks-for-particular-words-from-a-paragraph-in-react/58000546?noredirect=1#comment102414120_58000546

Answer (score 3):

When you simply want to change series of button style change. (example Tab bar buttons, one button selected others not )
simply use conditional styles

```
style={[this.state.yourstate ? styles.selectedButtonStyle : styles.normalButtonStyle]}
```

Comment: I need to check 5 condtions then how can I use this solution? Can you explain please.

Comment: you can go with nested conditions like this `style={[this.state.firstCondition ? styles.selectedButtonStyle : this.state.secondCondition? : styles.anotherStye :styles.normalButtonStyle]}
` but not sure how it affect the performance of the rendering